# Package Spring framework application to war using Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

I'm following a simple official Spring tutorial guide [Enabling Cross Origin Requests for a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/), you can download file from its [github repo](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-rest-service-cors.git).

I am trying to package this application to war file using Maven and deploy it on tomcat, so I follow another official Spring document on [Packaging executable jar and war files](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging) and I change the `pom.xml` so that it has:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I also change the java version to 7:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>
```

My IDE is Eclipse Luna 4.4.2, so I saved the new `pom.xml` file, right click project, select `Maven` -> `updated the project`, then I right click the project, select `run as` -> `Run on Server` select Tomcat server, and it failed to load the content and the error page looks like this:

[image]

I don't know how can I get this fixed. I think my tomcat is OK because I can run other web applications on it. My OS is Windows 7 64 bit, Java is JDK 7, maven is 3.3.3

Tomcat Error trace:

```
...
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
Aug 04, 2015 12:10:12 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Aug 04, 2015 12:10:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5156)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:809)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1920)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:157)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    ... 11 more

Aug 04, 2015 12:10:12 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/gs-rest-service-cors] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 04, 2015 12:10:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Aug 04, 2015 12:10:12 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Aug 04, 2015 12:10:12 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2439 ms
```

Complete `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service-cors</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Comment: this project is not deployed or as u mentioned project name addressbar .You added any landing page file in `web.xml` file ? Try to call some jsp page(full path of page) from addressbar

Comment: If you use `<scope>provided</scope>` this means it's expected to be in the environment you deploy it to...in other words it will not being packaged into the appropriate war file. If you like to have packaged just remove the line `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: @khmarbaise, I removed the line `<scope>provided</scope>` and redeploy the project, same error appears.

Comment: Could you post the complete POM? It seems that something is wrong with the Jersey dependency. Do you provide a `SpringBootServletInitializer` as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)?

Comment: @SteffenKreutz, complete POM added.

Comment: The logs say that a class from Jersey can not be found and I don't see Jersey as a dependency.

Comment: @SteffenKreutz If I keep the original `pom.xml` and just run it as a Spring boot application everything works fine, so I guess Jersey is already added to dependency implicitly by Spring boot, but I don't know why when I package to war and it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to specify the dependency in the child project. This is described in the maven guide here http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management

so, in your case, you need to add this dependency in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

---

To address your next problem. It seems that the `Application` class in your war file has not prepared for traditional deployment. therefore, you need to change it into something like this :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

for further reference, you could check this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html)

Comment: I tried your solution, the error on jersey dependency is gone, but the page is still not found, it should return json file as expected.

Comment: Hi, is there any error message or stacktrace on the log?

Comment: There is no error in tomcat log but it's not deployed correctly, browser still show the same http status 404 error as shown above. You can get the json response correctly on your machine?

Comment: yes, i'm able to get the json response. you tried the this URL right `/gs-rest-service-cors-0.1.0/greeting`? as you did not map any controller for path `/`.

Comment: I tried `gs-rest-service-cors-0.1.0/greeting`, but I still get 404 error.

Comment: strange, then could you try upload the war somewhere so I can use it in my local environment to check what is missing?

Comment: Here is a [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8z8v5az2j7uncza/gs-rest-service-cors-0.1.0.war?dl=0)